# UIButton image in NavigationItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

please tell me. I am trying to assign UIButton to titleView from navigationItem with an inscription and image. The inscription appears normal, but the image does not appear, and the indentation has under it (the inscription is shifted to the right from the center)

```
    UIButton* openMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [openMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(openCloseMenuAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [openMenu setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [openMenu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = openMenu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to give openMenu a size. You could try `[openMenu sizeToFit]` and see how that looks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `imageEdgeInset` and `titleEdgeInset` properties of `UIButton` to position title and image inside of a button.
2. Set frame of your `UIButton`

   ```
   titleButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44);
   ```
3. Assign the title view in view controllers viewDidLoad: method using

   ```
   self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton;
   ```